# Copying values from dataframe cell to other cell in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a problem with chain-indexing in a Pandas dataframe, which I know has to be avoided.

I am checking a dataframe for identical start and end dates in two different columns. If they are identical, I want to read the same value to a third column in the same row, which is the exact date column.

The dataframe looks like this:

| index | factoid_ID | pers_ID | pers_name | alternative_names | event_type | event_after-date | event_before-date | event_start | event_end | event_date | pers_title | pers_function | place_name | inst_name | rel_pers | source_quotations | additional_info | comment | info_dump | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3342 | API | Georg Christian Gottlieb Theophil Wedekind | n/a | Rezeption | n/a | n/a | 1788-11-09 | 1788-11-09 | n/a | Dr., med. / Dr., phil. h.c. | Mitglied | Mainz | Universität Mainz, Medizinische Fakultät | n/a | n/a | auf Mitteilung eines kurfürstlichen Beschlusses vom 05.07.1788 erfolgte seine Aufnahme ohne Prüfung. | n/a | n/a | ProfAPI |

So far, I am trying to use this:

```
# SAME START/AFTER AND END/BEFORE DATE = EXACT DATE
      # be careful to avoid chain-indexing in dataframe
      # use multi-axis indexing (df.loc['a', '1']) instead
      
      if e_df['event_start'].equals(e_df['event_end']):
        new_date=e_df['event_start'].values[0]
        #print(new_date)
        f_unique.loc[x, 'event_date']=new_date
      if e_df['event_after-date'].equals(e_df['event_before-date']):
        new_date=e_df['event_after-date'].values[0]
        #print(new_date)
        f_unique.loc[x, 'event_date']=new_date # NOT WORKING!!
      if len(e_df["event_date"].values[0])>=4:
        new_date=e_df["event_date"].values[0]
        f_unique.loc[x, 'event_start']=new_date
        f_unique.loc[x, 'event_end']=new_date
      else:
        new_date=e_df['event_date'].values[0]
        f_unique.loc[x, 'event_date']=new_date
```

In this code section, `f_unique` is the entire dataframe with over 9000 rows. `e_df` is the individual row I am analysing as I am going through the rows one by one. `x` is the index from "0" to `len(f_unique)`.

If I look at `f_unique` after the operation, the values have unfortunately not been updated. How can I fix this?

My expected output is this:

| index | factoid_ID | pers_ID | pers_name | alternative_names | event_type | event_after-date | event_before-date | event_start | event_end | event_date | pers_title | pers_function | place_name | inst_name | rel_pers | source_quotations | additional_info | comment | info_dump | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3342 | API | Georg Christian Gottlieb Theophil Wedekind | n/a | Rezeption | n/a | n/a | 1788-11-09 | 1788-11-09 | 1788-11-09 | Dr., med. / Dr., phil. h.c. | Mitglied | Mainz | Universität Mainz, Medizinische Fakultät | n/a | n/a | auf Mitteilung eines kurfürstlichen Beschlusses vom 05.07.1788 erfolgte seine Aufnahme ohne Prüfung. | n/a | n/a | ProfAPI |

Maybe iteration through the rows is already the wrong approach in this case, but I am also doing other things later in the code, e.g. duplicating some rows if they contain certain trigger events.

Comment: Can you show a sample data? And what the expected output should be

Answer (score 0):

I would assign your `event_date` column using a function like `np.where`. This works in the format of `np.where(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. For example, the following should be a start towards replacing your first two if statements:

```
f_unique['event_date'] = np.where(f_unique.event_start == f_unique.event_end, f_unique.event_start, 
                      (np.where(f_unique.event_after-date== f_unique.event_before-date, f_unique.event_after-date, 
                      <some_default_value>))
```